# How can I recluster a table hosted in SQL Azure

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

Normally in SQL Server, running the following would be fine:

> ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeLog DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ChangeLog
>
> ALTER TABLE dbo.ChangeLog ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ChangeLog 
>       PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ChangeLogID)
>
> CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_ChangeLog_FTRequestID 
>       ON dbo.ChangeLog (FTRequestID);

However, when trying to run it against a database hosted by Azure, I get the following error:

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of
>   SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

Obviously, if I try to create a second clustered index first, I get this error instead:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.ChangeLog'.
>   Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_ChangeLog' before creating
>   another

This seems to be a catch 22.

Is there any way I can get around this without dropping and recreating the entire table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heaps are not supported on the current version of SQL Database. Please upgrade your SQL Database server to [SQL Database Update V12](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/).

Comment: Okay.  I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: Worked great once I upgraded.  The "how to upgrade" link was really buried: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-upgrade/